# Change the way time is displayed in query

Tags: php, mysqli

I fetch a series of times from the database which represent competitors lap times. I have got the database set as TIME which shows 00:00:00. It also adds up the total at the end.

I am wanting to change it so that it does not show all the 0's if for example a time of 53 seconds is entered (0:53) would be shown. I want to do this just to tidy the webpage up. Same for the total that shows 00:00:53 for the above example I would prefer it to be 0:53. If there is a minutes included to show 1:53, ten minutes 10:53, hour 1:10:53 etc.

```
<?php
//MySqli Select Query
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT *, TIME(r1 + r2 + r3 + r4 + r5 + r6 + r7 + r8 + r9 + r10 + r11 + r12 + r13 + r14 + r15 + r16 + r17 + r18 + r19 + r20 + r21 + r22 + r23 + r24 + r25 + r26 + r27 + r28 + r29 + r30 + r31 + r32 + r33 + r34 + r35 + r36 + r37 + r38 + r39 + r40 + r41 + r42 + r43 + r44 + r45 + r46 + r47 + r48 + r49 + r50) AS total FROM test");
$title = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM test_info");

$all_cols=array("rt1" => "r1","rt2"=> "r2","rt3"=> "r3","rt4"=> "r4","rt5"=> "r5","rt6" => "r6","rt7"=> "r7","rt8"=> "r8","rt9"=> "r9","rt10"=> "r10","rt11" => "r11","rt12"=> "r12","rt13"=> "r13","rt14"=> "r14","rt15"=> "r15","rt16" => "r16","rt17"=> "r17","rt18"=> "r18","rt19"=> "r19","rt20"=> "r20","rt21" => "r21","rt22"=> "r22","rt23"=> "r23","rt24"=> "r24","rt25"=> "r25","rt26" => "r26","rt27"=> "r27","rt28"=> "r28","rt29"=> "r29","rt30"=> "r30","rt31" => "r31","rt32"=> "r32","rt33"=> "r33","rt34"=> "r34","rt35"=> "r35","rt36" => "r36","rt37"=> "r37","rt38"=> "r38","rt39"=> "r39","rt40"=> "r40","rt41" => "r41","rt42"=> "r42","rt43"=> "r43","rt44"=> "r44","rt45"=> "r45","rt46" => "r46","rt47"=> "r47","rt48"=> "r48","rt49"=> "r49","rt50"=> "r50",);

while ($t = $title->fetch_assoc()){
    // remember empty cols
    $empty_cols=array();

    echo "<table width=\"100%\" cellpadding=\"5\" cellspacing=\2\" class=\"entrywriting\" align=\"center\">
    <tr align=\"center\">
    <td>Overall</td>
    <td>Competitor</td>";

    foreach ($all_cols as $col => $value) {
        if (!empty($t[$col])) {
            echo "<td>" . $t[$col] . "</td>";
        } else {
            // set this column as empty for later
            $empty_cols[]=$col;
        }
    } unset($col); unset($value);
    echo "
    <td>Total</td>
    </tr>";
}

//set counter
$counter = 1;
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr align=\"center\">";
    echo "<td>" . $counter . "</td>";
    echo '<td>'.$row["driver"].'</td>';

    foreach ($all_cols as $col => $value) {
        if (!in_array($col, $empty_cols)) {
            // echo non-empty values
            echo '<td>'.$row[$value].'</td>';
        }
    } unset($col); unset($value);
    echo '<td>'.$row["total"].'</td>';

    $counter++; //increment count by 1
}  
echo "</table>";

?>
```

So I need r1 - r50 to only show times entered in brief rather than full 00:00:00 and total to do the same.

So I have added just under select * from test_info

```
function timeformat($time) {
// Convenience identifiers
$hh = 0; $mm = 0; $ss = 0; 
// Explode the time
$timecomp = explode($time);
// Analyse and return 
if ($timecomp[$hh] = "00" && $timecomp[$mm] = "00") {
    return '0:'.$ss;
} else 
    // Continue remaining tests from hereon 
     if ($timecomp[$hh] = "00" && $timecomp[$mm] = "01") {
    return ':'.$mm.$ss;
} 
}
```

I have replace two lines in the code to

```
echo '<td>'.timeformat($row[$value]).'</td>';
echo '<td>'.timeformat($row["total"]).'</td>';
```

I am getting

explode() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a function which takes the time in the hh:mm:ss format and returns a string in the format you want.

Code for the function:

```
function formattime($time) {

    $timecomp = explode(':', $time);
    $hh = (int) $timecomp[0]; // Cast as integer
    $mm = (int) $timecomp[1]; // Cast as integer
    $ss = $timecomp[2]; // Keep '00' format

    if ($hh == 0) {
        return $mm.':'.$ss;
    } else {
        return $hh.':'.$mm.':'.$ss;
    }
}
```

Executing:

```
echo (formattime('00:00:53')); echo '<br>';
echo (formattime('02:00:53')); echo '<br>';
echo (formattime('00:07:53')); echo '<br>';
```

gives:

0:53

2:0:53

7:53

Comment: Thanks - there is a syntax error on line 7 which i think is the ] .. I have taken this out and it finds no error. Where should I add this in my code? Would the $row['total'] stay as that?

Comment: Yeah, there is an extra ] there. Sorry. As I suggested, put the code in a function that's called e.g. timeformat($time). Then use the function where you echo the time, if I understand your code correctly, it could be echo "<td>" . timeformat($t[$col]) . "</td>";

Comment: im struggling to do it, i dont understand where it should go.

Comment: In which line in the code do you write the times which currently are written in the full hh:mm:ss format?

Comment: echo '<td>'.$row[$value].'</td>'; (these are individual times) and echo '<td>'.$row["total"].'</td>'; (total of individual times)

Comment: OK. Then use your function (e.g. timeformat) like this: echo '<td>'.timeformat($row[$value]).'</td>.

Comment: I have done the above but I dont know how to write the timeformat, i have got; timeformat;
// Convenience identifiers
$hh = 0; $mm = 0; $ss = 0;
// Explode the time
$timecomp = explode($time);
// Analyse and return 
if ($timecomp[$hh] = "00" && $timecomp[$mm] = "00") {
    return '0:'.$ss;
} else {
    // Continue remaining tests from hereon 
    if ($timecomp[$hh] = "00") {
    return .$mm':'.$ss;
}

Comment: Joseph, I can't teach you program PHP, this is not he forum for that. Read about PHP functions here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php.

Comment: I have updated my question, I do not understand what ive done wrong - not getting errors but not getting results